# Margin being added to div element when changing it's width within react-modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-modal

I have a react-modal with a div inside. Inside the div, I have a component which is essentially just another div with some divs/buttons inside. If I remove all styling form my code, my component will take up 100% of the modal.

However if I change my component to have the style `{width : 50%}`, my component only takes up 50% of the width as expected, but I get a margin to the right that takes up the other 50%. I've tried everything I can think of including wrapping it in another div, setting the margin to 0 etc.

How can I investigate this?

[image]

Comment: Set the width on the parent div (the parent of imageSelectContainer) to 100% and ensure the background colour isn't managed by the imageSelectContainer class.

Comment: That is already the case with the example in the question.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood - you've set the width to 50%, I imagine the yellow on the right is actually the result of you select the imageSelectContainer in the console? And the div is now 50% the width of it's container, the margin is representative of the space now left, it is not necessarily showing that margin has been applied.

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot is not clear. My mouse is in the margin part of the style box which highlights the margin within the UI

Comment: It tells you as much in the bottom right hand corner, as it would say how much margin was being applied at each side, but it doesn't. What you're seeing as margin is merely the lack of anything else.

Comment: You may be looking to change the display of the div if you want it gone i.e. inline-block instead of block